# How I catch Python PyQt5 QTreeWidget pressing enter (return) key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtreewidget

I am trying to run `enterFunc()` when pressing enter (return) key. But not working. Here is the code and what is the true code?:

```
class myForm(QMainWindow):

    ...
    def keyPressEvent(self,event):
                    if(event.key()==Qt.Key_Enter):
                        enterFunc()
    ...
    myForm.myTreeWidget.keyPressEvent(self,event)
    ...
```

Comment: where  QTreeWidget?

Comment: Do you want to press enter inside a QTreeWidget item or where?

Comment: QTreeWidget on the myForm. And I want to press enter inside a selected QTreeWidget item. And I get this error: myForm.myTreeWidget.keyPressEvent(self,event)

NameError: name 'event' is not defined

Comment: if you want help you must provide a [mcve], if you do not know what it is read the link, please take the time to do it.

Comment: I found this: `myForm.myTreeWidget.activated.connect(enterFunc)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `xxxEvent` are not signals and should not be invoked, if you want to listen to one of them you should use an event filter as shown below, on the other hand you should not use the `Qt::Key_Enter` key but the `Qt::Key_Return` key:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, uic


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        uic.loadUi("ui_mainwindow.ui",self)
        self.myTreeWidget.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj == self.myTreeWidget:
            if  event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress:
                if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:
                    print("enter pressed")
        return super(MainWindow, self).eventFilter(obj, event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Or more easily use `QShortcut`:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, uic


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        uic.loadUi("ui_mainwindow.ui",self)

        shorcut = QtWidgets.QShortcut(QtCore.Qt.Key_Return, 
            self.myTreeWidget, 
            context=QtCore.Qt.WidgetShortcut,
            activated=self.some_function)

    def some_function(self):
        print("some_function")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```